# ionic cordova build android fails `Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: ionic-framework

I installed Ionic Cordova BackgroundLocation plugin but when I building myapp then it gives me error like `Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.` or you can see below image 
[image]

Comment: It seems like android version issue. SDK version is not matching with the needs your plugin is needing.

Comment: I had same issue I tried removing and adding the android platform and it worked try if that works

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade your buildToolsVersion to "higher version" like this:

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
```

If you didn't install the buildTools for this version, please download it with SDKManager as hint.

Comment: install buildToolsVersion 25.0.1 but getting same error